# iText 7 Hello World example fails with NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: itext7

Working down the very first example of the itext 7 code causes a NoClassDefFoundError at step 4.
If anyone can point to where the error is coming from would be helpful?

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph

//step 1 - writer
writer = new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream(DEST))
//step 2 - PDF
pdf = new PdfDocument(writer)
//step 3 - document
document = new Document(pdf)
//step 4 - content
document.add( new Paragraph ( 'Hello World!' ) )
```

this produces

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.itextpdf.io.font.FontProgramFactory
```

code is being run under Groovy which is why it is slightly more sparse
The IO, Kernel and Layout jars are loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Did you watch the video on how to install iText 7? The error message tells you that you didn't include the IO jar. My assumption is that you have added the kernel and the layout jar to your CLASSPATH, but that you overlooked adding the io jar.

These are some of the documented dependencies in the [Before we start: installing iText 7](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/installing-itext-7) section of the Jump-start tutorial:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>io</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

As explained in the videos, the io jar is a dependency of the kernel jar.

You write:

> The IO, Kernel and Layout jars are loaded.

The error message you shared, tells me that the IO jar isn't loaded. The `com.itextpdf.io.font.FontProgramFactory` class is stored in this jar.

Comment: @johnrenfrew The error message tells me otherwise. Either the error message is wrong, or you are. As a developer, I have more trust in what error messages tell me than in what human beings say. I even trust error messages more than what I think myself.

Comment: The error is indeed mine, but is not what you think, There is a dependency on SLF4J which I missed at the bottom of the examples, as I imagine it is presumed loaded if you use an IDE, which we are not... I am unsure of why including it makes the error disappear though..

Comment: @johnrenfrew That's indeed very strange. When I "forget" the logging, I get a warning in my IDE, but it't not a "fatal error." You could be right that it's related to the IDE in some way...

Comment: @johnrenfrew how does your building/packaging process resolve transitive dependencies? Maybe it doesn't...

Comment: @mkl I am not building/packaging in the conventional sense. It is a plugin to the FileMaker environment which gives me a JVM in which I can run a compiled function (lines of code) I have to load the jars into the JVM before I can instantiate the function and use it as this is therefore bound to that JVM at runtime. If I load all the dependant jars (including thise not specifically reference as an import) then the function I create will work.

Comment: I am coming back to this question as I still not found a way round this and would like to make some progress. The assumptions made so far is that this is being written in an IDE to then be compiled, which is not true, but using the method above which works perfectly for itext 5.n